# Laravel- Compare 2 time strings in a request

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have a form where I am asking for start time and end time. I get them as string now I want to check in request that End Time should not be less than Start Time.
How can I achieve this in laravel request?

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'hospital'   =>  'required',
            'meeting_date'    => 'required|after:yesterday',
            'start_time'    =>  'required',
            'end_time'  =>  'required'
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution,

```
$inputs = array(
  'start_date' => '2013-01-20',
  'end_date'   => '2013-01-15'
);

$rules = array(
  'start_date' => 'required|before_date:end_date',
  'end_date'   => 'required'
);

$messages = array(
  'before_date' => ":attribute must be before :other"
);

$validation = Validator::make($inputs, $rules, $messages);

if( $validation->fails() )
{

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($validation->errors);
  echo '</pre>';

}//if it didn't validate
```

From https://laravelish.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/compare-2-dates-from-input-in-validation/